# React warning disappeared somehow. How do I bring them back?

Tags: reactjs

There are tons of questions online about how to disable react warnings. However, I just want to bring them back because I find them really helpful.

Currently, all I get in console is in the following screenshot. How do I fix everything?

[image: Related warning I get]

Comment: What did you do to make the warnings go way (other than writing correct code in the first place so they aren't emitted)? Based on your screenshot it seems you are still seeing warnings, so it's unclear what the issue is.

Comment: I reinstalled node modules for another problem I think. The warnings I am looking for is warnings for useEffect and useCallback dependencies, and stuff like '=='. They usually pop up in console after I refresh the page but now they are nowhere to be found

Comment: Those sound more like eslinting warnings/errors. What IDE are you using? Is the linting tool enabled & configured?